# Angular2 - How to programmatically blur component?

Tags: angular

I use a calendar type datepicker from PrimeNG. It has a popup calendar but also allows a textfield input via keyboard.
I use a `HostListener` in my component to capture the `Enter` keypress to initiate a request for the new selected timerange.

```
@HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
keyboardInput(event: any) { if(event.key === "Enter") this.reloadData(); }
```

The problem is that the popped up calendar doesn't disappear when I press Enter.
Is there a way to programmatically blur the component?